# Aspect Oriented SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, aop

Are there any libraries, open source or otherwise, that can be installed into a SQL Server instance (2008 or later) that can enforce AOP standards?  I'd really like to avoid enforcing cross-cutting concerns with templates across our development staff.  AOP seems like the best option, if it's available.

If it doesn't exist already, I'll try to roll my own.

EDIT:

Some examples might be subclassing Table to make specific kinds of tables, like mixin characteristics.  I'm in a data warehouse environment with a lot of audit requirements so we create bitemporal tables a lot.  It would be awesome to have a

```
CREATE BITEMPORAL TABLE
```

statement that would add transaction and valid time and modify CRUD statements against those tables.  (Yes, I know that views and triggers can do this, somewhat.)  A harder thing to accomplish would be stored procedures with specific logging or transaction characteristics, like

```
CREATE PROC FOO /* VERBOSE, ATOMIC, SERIALIZABLE */
```

and have the body automatically wrapped with the appropriate T-SQL to do those things.  Yes, it's possible to add stored procedures to take those arguments and do SQL generation and compile those artifacts.  But the drawback is that there's no enforcement - a developer may bypass the procedure and use CREATE PROC directly - and that the content in syscomments is the generated code, not the AOP annotated version, which breaks the abstraction.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would want to enforce?

Comment: I think it would be really interesting to know the intended use. Is it basically hooking in stuff before and/or after queries, or even more involved?

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you are interested in having a look at AO4SQL - a programming language that brings AO concepts to SQL. Conceptually, the tool works with any SQL server.

You can download my paper *"AO4SQL: Towards an Aspect-Oriented Extension for SQL"* that was published at the RAM-SE 2011: http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~manuel/Events/RAM-SE11/RAMSE11papers.zip

Keep in mind that AO4SQL is a prototype tool, but if you would likt to join an open source project ... get in contact with me.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I've never even thought about applying AOP techniques to a SQL Server.

With SQL Server 2008, I believe you have the ability to call .NET code, so you could maybe work in a standard AOP tool like PostSharp or Castle DynamicProxy that way.